How to insert records from table A to table B, avoiding inserting records from table A that already exist in table B
My table 'B' is the table where the data will be definitely stored without having repetitions while table 'A' is created to store any information including repetitions, this can happen because the system that uses table B can fail and when they try launching the process again does not have a filter that validates that the rows that are being inserted already exist, which is why it creates table 'A'.
What I'm trying to do is that if the row I want to pass from A already exists in table B then it won't be inserted.
I have created a procedure but it is having problems processing millions of rows.
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_emp (p_date IN Date) AS
   array_nonrepeated  clob;
   curr_num_transaction varchar2(50);
   BEGIN
        --Loop through each record in table A
        FOR loop_table_a IN (SELECT num_transaction FROM table_a where date_transaction = p_date) LOOP
            --Query to validate if curr value of loop exist in table b
            SELECT num_transaction INTO curr_num_transaction from table_b where num_transaction = loop_table_a.num_transaction;
            
            --If condition
            IF curr_num_transaction IS NULL
            THEN
                INSERT INTO table_b(num_transaction,date_transaction,total,user_insert)
                SELECT num_transaction,date_transaction,total,user_insert FROM table_a where num_transaction = curr_num_transaction;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
   END;
/


Use the merge statement (d r gives an example in his answer) and add a parallel hint. If the # of rows you are inserting every time is truly massive, you may also want to enable parallel dml (execute immediate 'alter session enable parallel dml') before the merge, and then hint the merge (merge /*+ parallel(16) */ into...)

--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table A (ID_A Number);
Insert Into A Values(1);
Insert Into A Values(1);
Insert Into A Values(2);
Insert Into A Values(2);
Insert Into A Values(3);

Create Table B (ID_B Number);
Insert Into B Values(1);
Insert Into B Values(2);

One option to do it is using MERGE INTO :
... USING sql code fetches distinct values from table A. ON condition makes a merge and WHEN NOT MATCHED (ID not present in table B) does the actual insert - simplified description in code:
--    S Q L :
MERGE INTO B 
-- USING sql should select all columns that you need to insert
-- into table B as well as those needed to be compared with columns
-- in table B to check if particular row is already present there (1 to 1)
-- The conditions to do the check are in ON clause after the USING sql
USING ( Select Distinct ID_A 
        From A
      ) x ON( x.ID_A = B.ID_B ) -- ON clause check for matched row in table B
                                -- this should match rows from USING sql and table B 1 to 1 
WHEN  NOT MATCHED THEN 
-- if there is no matching row in table B do the Insert
--   INSERT (list of columns in table B to put values in) VALUES (respective list of values from x to put in table B)
INSERT (ID_B) VALUES(x.ID_A)

Another option is to use subquery which will select just rows that are not present in table B (Left Join Where ID_B Is Null):
Insert Into B 
( Select    Distinct ID_A
  From      A
  Left Join B ON(B.ID_B = A.ID_A)
  Where     ID_B Is Null  );

And another option is using Not Exists correlated subquery:
Insert Into B
( Select Distinct ID_A From A Where Not Exists(Select 1 From B Where ID_B = A.ID_A) )

With sample data from above all will insert ID 3 in table B.
ADDITION:
Not knowing your tables' descriptions nor keys, indexes or data - below is one example how it works with multiple columns.
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table A (NUM_TRANSACTION Number, DATE_TRANSACTION Date, TOTAL Number, USER_INSERT Varchar2(255));
Insert Into  A Values ( 101, DATE '2024-05-03', 100, 'A' );
Insert Into  A Values ( 101, DATE '2024-05-04', 200, 'A' );
Insert Into  A Values ( 102, DATE '2024-05-05', 300, 'B' );
Insert Into  A Values ( 102, DATE '2024-05-05', 400, 'C' );
Insert Into  A Values ( 103, DATE '2024-05-06', 500, 'D' );

Create Table B (NUM_TRANSACTION Number, DATE_TRANSACTION Date, TOTAL Number, USER_INSERT Varchar2(255));
Insert Into  B Values(101, DATE '2024-05-03', 300, 'A');
Insert Into  B Values(103, DATE '2024-05-06', 500, 'D');

Assuming that primary key of table B is NUM_TRANSACTION column, the USING (sql query code) of MERGE INTO statement should result with unique values of NUM_TRANSACTION column along with LAST_DATE_TRANSACTION, sum of TOTAL and LIST_USER_INSERT columns that should be inserted in table B columns NUM_TRANSACTION, DATE_TRANSACTION, TOTAL, USER_INSERT respectively. The complete code for this scenario would be:
--    S Q L :
MERGE INTO B 
USING ( Select  DISTINCT  
                  a1.*, LISTAGG(Distinct a2.USER_INSERT, ',') WITHIN GROUP 
                            (Order By a2.USER_INSERT) Over(Partition By a1.NUM_TRANSACTION, a1.LAST_DATE_TRANSACTION) "LIST_USER_INSERT"
        From    ( Select    a1.NUM_TRANSACTION,  Max(a1.DATE_TRANSACTION) "LAST_DATE_TRANSACTION", Sum(a1.TOTAL) "TOTAL"
                  From      A a1
                  Group By  NUM_TRANSACTION
                ) a1
        Inner Join A a2 ON(a2.NUM_TRANSACTION = a1.NUM_TRANSACTION And
                        a2.DATE_TRANSACTION = a1.LAST_DATE_TRANSACTION)
      ) x ON( x.NUM_TRANSACTION = B.NUM_TRANSACTION ) 
WHEN  NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (NUM_TRANSACTION, DATE_TRANSACTION, TOTAL, USER_INSERT) 
        VALUES(x.NUM_TRANSACTION, x.LAST_DATE_TRANSACTION, x.TOTAL, x.LIST_USER_INSERT) 

/*  R e s u l t :
1 row merged.  */

Test table B content after MERGE_
--  Test table B 
SELECT * FROM B ORDER BY NUM_TRANSACTION
/*
NUM_TRANSACTION DATE_TRANSACTION      TOTAL USER_INSERT
--------------- ---------------- ---------- -----------
            101 03.05.24                300 A          
            102 05.05.24                700 B,C       -- Inserted Row 
            103 06.05.24                500 D           */


How can I add more fields not just the ID? I want to implement this option                          MERGE INTO B  USING ( Select Distinct ID_A          From A       ) x ON( x.ID_A = B.ID_B )  WHEN  NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID_B) VALUES(x.ID_A)

@CesarTepetla Just updated the answer with additional description in code.

@CesarTepetla Just posted an addition with multi columns example. We don't know your data or unique keys so this is just a guess showing how to do it in general - not solving the issue with your actual data. You should adjust it yourself to your actual context.

If you have a PRIMARY KEY defined on your table you can use the ignore row hint.

create table t1 (
 name varchar2 (20) primary key,
age number
 ); 

insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(t1(name)) */ into t1 values ('Johnny', 77);

 insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(t1(name)) */ into t1 values ('Pete' , 28); 

insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(t1(name)) */ into t1 values ('Sue' , 35);

 insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(t1(name)) */ into t1 values ('Johnny', null);


